# Object calling results in a endless recursion

Tags: javascript, recursion

I could need your help. At the moment I am trying to understand how JavaScript handle's classes and objects. So I wrote a little example:

```
function aClass(test, something_else){
    this.string1 = "I'am just a class !";
    this.string2 = "";
    this.methode1 = function(){
        console.log("Greetings :)");
        this.constructor("Called from method1","Pretty nice or ?");
    };
    console.log("Line 8 !");
    this.methode1();
    this.constructor = function(input1, input2){
        console.log("Method 2 was called !\n"+ input1 +"\n"+ input2);
    };
    this.constructor(test, something_else);
}

var object_contianer1 = new aClass("You");
object_contianer1.methode1();
```

But the call in line 9 (`this.methode1();`) seems to cause a endless recursion and I'm not sure why. If I remove this line, line 13 (`this.constructor(test, something_else);`) does not produce this recursion, so I was wondering what the reason is.

I hope one of you could explain it to me.

Comment: `this.constructor` before you assign your own fucntion, is pointer to `aClass`

Comment: mdn: [Object.prototype.constructor: Returns a reference to the Object function that created the instance's prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/constructor)

Comment: so if you assign `this.constructor = function(input1, input2){` before calling `this.methode1();` all work

Comment: @Grundy ok sorry to ask but I don't understand your answer. Why does this produce a recursion. I have no idea to be honest what this prototype stuff is :(

Comment: sorry to ask obvious, but how do you know it is endless recursion?

Comment: @webduvet i got the response from my Firefox who gave this error: [error](http://puu.sh/hbltA/fed87a3ef4.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`new aClass()` creates a new object with constructor `aClass`. Inside that function call, `this.constructor` refers to `aClass` itself.

Therefore this:

```
function aClass() {
  this.constructor();
}
```

Is directly equivalent to this, which clearly produces an infinite loop:

```
function aClass() {
  aClass();
}
```

Note that this only applies when you call `new aClass()`, because `new` sets `this` to "the object that is being created".

If you call `aClass()` without `new`, `this` will be the top-level object (`Window` in a browser). That will also fail, this time with a `TypeError`, because it is not legal to call `Window`.

Comment: ok that seems to make sens ... I guess, but how can I avoid it ?

Comment: @Feirell just not call `this.constructor`

Comment: @Grundy and how do I call a internal method ?

Comment: @Feirell, simple rename your method and use it like redular method